# I am unable to get "spack mirror add" to work

Tags: mirror, spack

I decided I wanted to install `gcc@10.2` with spack, so I ran the command `spack --insecure install gcc@10.2`. This attempts to download `https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-10.2/gcc-10.2.tar.xz`, which no longer exists.

I downloaded `gcc-10.2.tar.xz` from a valid mirror, and attempted to add a mirror.

I've tried variants of the form

```
$ spack mirror add local_filesystem gcc-10.2.tar.xz
```

However, `spack install gcc@10.2` still gives the same answer.

I can't figure out how to get spack to use the mirror for installing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you would first use spack to *create* the mirror, e.g.:

```
spack mirror create -d /tmp/mirror gcc@10.2.0
```

This will create the directory /tmp/mirror and download a tarball to /tmp/mirror_source_cache, with symbolic link to /tmp/mirror/gcc:

```
$ ll /tmp/mirror/gcc/gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 willmore jlse 99 Nov 30 20:32 /tmp/mirror/gcc/gcc-10.2.0.tar.xz -> ../_source-cache/archive/b8/b8dd4368bb9c7f0b98188317ee0254dd8cc99d1e3a18d0ff146c855fe16c1d8c.tar.xz
```

Even if you aren't able to create the mirror automatically with `spack mirror create`, you can still put the tarball directly where that symlink is.

Then add the mirror (which is just that directory):

```
spack mirror add my_mirror file:///tmp/mirror
```

TLDR: The mirror isn't just the tarball, but it contains the tarball. Also, you may try adding the public mirror:

```
spack-public    https://spack-llnl-mirror.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
```

Comment: I tried the above steps, then asked spack to install gcc@10.2.0. It went to amazonaws rather than use the tarball I downloaded. So, it seems to be useless. :(

Comment: It will probably check the public mirror first. If you remove that, and if you've added your mirror, it *should* fall back to that.